# How to implement a trait for generic type in Rust? (E0207)

Tags: generics, rust

I am trying to build a math library, mostly for the learning experience.

Right now, I have multiple implementations for a Matrix trait

```
pub trait Matrix<T> {

    fn add(&mut self, other: Self) -> &mut Self;
}
```

One is a stack based Matrix:

```
pub struct StackMatrix<T, const Rows: usize, const Cols: usize> {
    rows: [[T; Cols]; Rows],
}
```

And another is a heap based Matrix:

```
pub struct HeapMatrix<T> {
    cells: Vec<T>,
}
```

Now I want to support addition of these matricies. I already know that I need to have this `add` method in the Matrix trait for this to work, because Rust doesn't have the same templating mechanism as C++ and your code actually has to compile without instantiation. So each of these matricies will provide the `add` method.

However, this is an implementation detail. I would love any implementation of these matricies to use the idiomatic operator `+` (and many more obviously). But I do NOT want to implement the same operator for each of the types. Granted, for now there are only two, but maybe in the future there will be a `GpuMatrix` or a `PyTorchMatrix`, etc.

So I tried this:

```
impl<T, TMatrix: Matrix<T>> Add<TMatrix> for TMatrix {
    type Output = TMatrix;

    fn add(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
    }
}
```

Which yields:

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `T` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
```

So I know this error and in many cases it does make sense. However, in this particular case it isn't really warranted, since all the types I want to implement this operator for are in fact within my crate. It's just that technically they could be in another. So essentially, what I need here is a way to tell the compiler that only generic types from my crate are supposed to be applied here. That doesn't seem possible right now, but I really do not see the difficulty of supporting it. Like I could just go and remove the generic, replace it with HeapMatrix and StackMatrix, and the code would compile just fine.

Is there any other way to solve this with Rust without writing these operators as macros or re-writing them for each type?

Conceptually, something like

```
impl<T, TMatrix: Matrix<T> + crate> Add<TMatrix> for TMatrix {
    type Output = TMatrix;

    fn add(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
    }
}
```

to restrict the generic argument to types from this crate?

Comment: What role does the type parameter `T` serve?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman It's the cell type of the Matrix. Like `u8`, `String` whatever you wanna put in there. But yeah I realize it actually needs to be `Add<TMatrix>`

Comment: A matrix can't implement `Matrix` with two different cell types, right? So it will be better to make this an associated type.

Comment: Yeah that's a good point. But I already changed that and the error is still there.

Comment: The same error, or a different error?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Same one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about it the opposite way: instead of having an `add()` method in `Matrix`, and a blanket implementation of `std::ops::Add` for that (which you can't do due to the orphan rules), implement `std::ops::Add` for your matrix types, and enforce that for `Matrix`:

```rust
pub trait Matrix<T>: std::ops::Add {}
```

Comment: This ended up working. Thanks. It was quite a bit more involved than adding this trait there but so far I think everything works as expected. My main concern was writing algorithms on `Matrix` and not on the specific implementations. That works fine if you always accept the `Matrix` as `fn my_op<TMatrix: Matrix>(lhs: TMatrix, rhs: TMatrix)`, so this seems to allow me to get the level of abstraction from the `Matrix` implementation that I wanted. But at the same time it more limiting than it needs to be. It'd be great for rust to offer a way to violate orphan rules in the same crate.

Comment: @Mara this is not an orphan rule problem, more of a "there can be at most a single instance of every trait for every type (after monomorphisation)" and if you read again your first definition with that in mind you see it's not true.

Comment: @jthulhu It is the orphan rules, because we could allow this impl and check with dependent crates that there is no conflicting implementations.